# .NET Threading : How to wait for other thread to finish some task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Assume I have method 
void SomeMethod(Action callback)
This method does some work in background thread and then invokes callback. The question is - how to block current thread until callback is called ?

There is an example

```
bool finished = false;
SomeMethod(delegate{
 finished = true;
});
while(!finished)
  Thread.Sleep();
```

But I'm sure there should be better way

Comment: If you're going to block the current thread until the work on the background thread is complete, could you just do the work on the current thread instead?

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't do the work in current thread.

Comment: Have you considered putting the code after the wait inside the thread then or using a callback/event? What you're describing is a synchronous operation. Is there maybe more information?

Comment: perhaps the current thread is also the main thread of a GUI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AutoResetEvent to signal when your thread is finished.

Check this code snippet:

```
    AutoResetEvent terminateEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    bool finished = false;
    SomeMethod(delegate
    {
        terminateEvent.Set();
    });
    terminateEvent.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed. Does it work faster than thread sleep ?

Comment: A spin-lock (constantly checking a flag in a while loop, possibly with a `Thread.Sleep`) is likely faster when the blocked time is very small, otherwise, `AutoResetEvent` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Check for `Thread.Join()` will work

[Example of this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0420__Thread/UseJointowaitforthreadstoend.htm)

Comment: The problem with Thread.Join is that other thread is not finished when it calls callback.